# Get metadata for all deleted files in folder

Tags: android, dropbox-api

How can i get the metadata of all the files that are there is the folder even if the files are deleted. Current function only returns the metadata of the files that are present in a folder and not which have been deleted

Answer (score 1):

See `included_deleted` in `metadata` API method reference: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api

Comment: But include_deleted is not included in the java implementation of metadata I guess